# Validate a Create and Edit DTO with nealy all same properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dto, data-transfer-objects

I have too very similar DTOs.

They differ only in the one property which identifies the Test resouce.

When I create now instead a EditAddTestDTO and make the

```
public int<Nullable> TestId {get;set;}
```

Then I can not put the RequireAttribute on it because it would not work in the Create-Scenario where I have not the TestId obviously.

How do you solve that problem?

Create 2 DTO`s as I already have or AddEditBaseDTO?

```
public class EditTestDTO
{        
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}

public class CreateTestDTO
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First of all - why do you create a nullable property which should be required?

Comment: Because of ... "Then I can not put the RequireAttribute on it because it would not work in the Create-Scenario where I have not the TestId obviously."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid sharing a base class. There's no logic you're trying to share between the classes so keep them clean and simple.

If you want to use some of the same code for both models add an interface instead and have the two classes implement it. This has the advantage that the interface can be defined in a different project with any services that use it.

EDIT:

You could have something like this, assuming you only need read access in your service, but it really depends what properties you need access to:

```
public interface ITestDTO
{
    DateTime Date { get; }
    int Number { get; }
    int SchoolClassCodeId { get; }
    int SchoolYearId { get; }
    int TestTypeId { get; }
    int? TestId { get; }
}

public class EditTestDTO : ITestDTO
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolClassCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolYearId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    int? ITestDTO.TestId { get { return TestId; } }
}

public class CreateTestDTO : ITestDTO
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolClassCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolYearId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }

    int? ITestDTO.TestId { get { return null; } }
}
```

The nullable TestId allows you to differentiate between edit and create in your service.

Comment: How would the interface look like? 5 properties? Pretty overhead?

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but I will not use it as its too much overhead. Properties have often no logic and the impl. for the interface is also empty.  I stick to KISS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class `TestDTO` which contains all necessary properties(but I believe my edited answer is better that creating all those abstraction stuff):

```
public abstract class TestDTO
{

   public abstract DateTime Date { get; set; }

   public abstract int Number { get; set; }

   public abstract int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }

   public abstract int SchoolyearId { get; set; }

   public abstract int TestTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

And then just implement properties in your others DTOs or just place those properties in your `CreateTestDTO` and just derive from it in `EditTestDTO` adding `TestId` property.

EDIT:

Then you can have following classes:

```
public class CreateTestDTO : TestDTO
{
   [Required]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int Number { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class EditTestDTO : TestDTO
{        
   [Required]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int Number { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int TestTypeId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int TestId { get; set; }
```

}

Another approach would be validating your model using `IValidatableObject` interface and adding a flag, which can be used during validation:

```
public class EditTestDTO : IValidatableObject
{        
   [Required]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int Number { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int TestTypeId { get; set; }

   public int? TestId { get; set; }

   public bool IsEdit {get;set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      if(IsEdit) 
      {
          if(!TestId.HasValue)
          {
              yield return new ValidationResult();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be a strong coupling between child and base class. What If I have to put a property in the EditTestDTO which must not exist in the CreateTestDTO? Then I am doomed...

Comment: @Elisa - naah, you misunderstood me. In that case you create `TestDTO`  and derive from it in both `CreateTestDTO` and `EditTestDTO`. It enables you to add whatever you like in both DTOs without impact on each other. I believe there are some fancy patterns for this particular case - it all depends on the result you'd like to see.

Comment: But then my CreateTestDTO would be empty with just the base properties. Derive something with no content makes no sense?!

Comment: @Elisa - what do you mean by 'no content'? DTO by definition has no real content. Since all those properties are abstract you have to implement them in both DTOs along with data annotations.

Comment: Ok much talk... we both get confused ;-) would you please add a code snippet for the EditTestDTO and CreateTestDTO too just as you did with the base TestDTO to see and show you my doubts please?